# How I fetch values from one column based on distinct values from other column?

Tags: mysql, sql, ssms

I have two columns in a table and I want a query to fetch First column values based on distinct values from Second column. Since, There are multiple combinations of First and second column I would like to have the first match from each combination.

DATASET:

| First Column | Second Column |
| --- | --- |
| A | abc |
| B | abc |
| C | abc |
| D | abc |
| F | abc |
| G | abc |
| H | qwe |
| I | qwe |
| J | jkl |
| K | jkl |
| L | jkl |
| M | uio |
| N | uio |

Excepted Output:

| First Column | Second Column |
| --- | --- |
| A | abc |
| H | qwe |
| J | jkl |
| M | uio |

Comment: Just use `MIN(col1)` and `GROUP BY col2`. This is beginner SQL.

Comment: The second column actually doesnt have numbers

Comment: It doesn't matter what it contains. `GROUP BY col2` works with any datatype.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `MIN(col1)` is what selects the first value from the first column in each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `MIN()` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT min(`First Column`) AS `First Column`, `Second Column`
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY `Second Column`
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f22a68/1)